# synchronization between multiregion Shops

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, ce-1.9.2.4, server-setup, country-regions

Our main business is in Germany and we try to sell our products in **China**. At first we used our existing infrastructure in Germany with new a new storeview, but the latency from China was very high. A Varnish cached page took ~12 Seconds.

So, we set up new server in Singapore. Singapore is the nearest AWS region to China. We also set up a read-replica which was also hosted in Singapore.
All read-transactions were very fast, but the writes to the master-database in Germany were still very high. To add a Product to the Cart it took ~4s. In our German store it took ~400ms. Even the replication lag was high.

A Solution which I thought about was to host a standalone Shops in China and synchronize everything to centralized systems like a ERP, PIM etc.
At the moment, we don't have a ERP or PIM and in my opinion we don't need it, because we have just ~50 Products, don't use automatic stock management and outsourced the shipping.

My second thought was, that we could use our Magento system in Germany as a centralized system and synchronize Products, Orders, Customer, etc. between the standalone Shops. If we synchronize everything with a cronjob the latency should no longer be the problem.

For me it's important that our Employees don't have to use multiple backends.

Does anybody has a similar problem and found a convenient solution?
Or is there already a good synchronization script for Magento?

P.S.: We tested the performance of our Chinese Site with a lot of local Chinese people in different regions in china and not from Germany :)